# (Android) Encrypting data disallowing awarness of the method used in the source code

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm currently helping on a project in which some data must be encrypted using some symmetric algorithm (a second level of encryption above the SSL/TLS connection which is currently implemented).

The problem is that if we extract the source code from the *.apk* (using tools like *ApkTool*, *dex2jar* & *Java Decompiler*) we can actually see the seed and the method used to generate the symmetric key and therefore encrypt and send valid data to the server.

Some questions then arise as how can we define the symmetric key in order to encrypt (very sensitive) data from the phone to the server but disallowing for someone how can extract the *.apk* to see the "way" the key is generated.

Thanks you very much in advance!
Warren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you could use Proguard to obfuscate your code.

In your build.gradle you can set **minifyEnabled** to **true** instead of (the default) false.
Which will then obfuscate your code.

Example:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems exactly what I'm looking for :D, I will try it to see the results.